# Как удалить из одномерного массива одноразрядные элементы?

Tags: pascal

задали задание по информатике, битый час ломаю голову. звучит задание так "напишите программу обработки одномерного массива, сформированного из случайных чисел, "выкинув" из него все одноразрядные элементы (т.е. новый массив содержит только двузначные числа)".
весь массив готов, не выходит только удаление. как написать такую программу?

```
program hir;
var A:array [1..10] of integer;
    i:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 10 do A[i]:=randome(99);
  for i:=1 to 10 do write (A[i],' ');
end.
```

Comment: перепишите в новый массив только двузначные

Comment: немного не поняла. что значит "перепишите в массив только двузначные", если у меня задача сделать программу, исключающую все одноразрядные элементы?

Comment: Если у вас в сумке яблоки и бананы, то, переложив в другую сумку только яблоки, вы избавитесь от бананов - разве не так?

Comment: хмм, хорошо, но как именно переложить яблоки программой? какой оператор и как для этого использовать?

Comment: А как вы заполняли массив? Вы же как-то складывали числа в массив?

Comment: Показывайте свой код, без этого разговор пустой.

Comment: program hir;
var A:array [1..10] of integer;
       i:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 10 do A[i]:=random(99);
if A<9 then (тут мои жалкие попытки понять и написать код по увеличению чисел)
for i:=1 to 10 do write (A[i],' ');
end.

Comment: Вопрос отредактируйте, код туда. Задание точно приведено? Динамические массивы вам известны? Если нет, то что делать, когда в массиве останется меньше чисел, чем было?

Comment: задание буквально скопированно из сообщения учителя. динамические массивы не проходили, нет. думаю, что так и надо, чтобы осталось меньше чисел, чем было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Randomize;
for i:=1 to 10 do 
   A[i]:= random(100);
for i:=1 to 10 do 
   write (A[i],' ');

cnt := 0;   {счётчик мелких}
for i:=1 to 10 do 
   if A[i] < 10 then
      Inc(cnt)
   else
      A[i - cnt] := A[i];
 
for i:=1 to 10 - cnt do  {выведем нужную часть массива}
   write (A[i],' ');
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, но есть пара вопросов. сейчас паскаль ругается на Inc, что делать?

Comment: Это что ещё за паскаль такой, что Inc не знает? может, вы cnt неправильно объявили? Надо Integer

Comment: о, теперь все заработало, спасибо огромное, вы меня спасли!!